# Move items to specific folder

Tags: applescript

I want a folder action that moves any items added to Desktop folder to a specific sub folder. The sub folder is generated weekly each Monday by automater. For this week that sub folder is called 'Desktop Week 02-18-2019'

I want to use folder actions so when any file is added to Desktop it is moved to that week sub folder.

As far as I understand I need to Find that sub folder and set it as a variable and move the original files that triggered the folder action into that specific sub folder.

Most solutions online only deal where the folder to move into name is already known.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave

Save this following AppleScript code as a .scpt file to folder….  /Users/YOUR SHORT NAME/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions.

```
property moveToFolder : (path to documents folder as text)
property folderNameContains : "Desktop Week"

on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    if weekday of (current date) is Tuesday then
        set theWeekday to 1
    else if weekday of (current date) is Wednesday then
        set theWeekday to 2
    else if weekday of (current date) is Thursday then
        set theWeekday to 3
    else if weekday of (current date) is Friday then
        set theWeekday to 4
    else if weekday of (current date) is Saturday then
        set theWeekday to 5
    else if weekday of (current date) is Sunday then
        set theWeekday to 6
    else if weekday of (current date) is Monday then
        set theWeekday to 0
    end if

    set moveToFolderCreationDate to short date string of ((current date) - (theWeekday * days))

    tell application "Finder"
        set dateStringForMakeFolder to my shortDateTID(moveToFolderCreationDate, {"/"})
        set a to length of (item 1 of words of dateStringForMakeFolder)
        if a is 1 then set dateStringForMakeFolder to (0 as text) & dateStringForMakeFolder
        try
            make new folder at moveToFolder ¬
                with properties {name:((folderNameContains & " " & dateStringForMakeFolder) as string)}
        end try
        set theFolder to folders of alias moveToFolder whose name contains dateStringForMakeFolder
        move theNewItems to (theFolder as alias) with replacing
    end tell
end adding folder items to

to shortDateTID(someText, delimiterListItems)
    set originalText to someText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiterListItems
    set tempText to text items of originalText
    set text item delimiters to "-"
    set cleanedText to tempText as text
end shortDateTID
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I placed this scpt within Folder Actions i then saved item into Desktop but nothing seems to of happened. Should I be manually attaching this script in automator somehow? or was it meant to drop into Folder Actions and work from offset?

Comment: I've updated script and saved and attached to desktop per screen video. Yet still nothing changes when items are dropped into desktop :/ am I right that I shouldn't have to change any line from your script at all?

Comment: Some notes that may or may not be helpful: ① Your last `if...then...else` conditional seems redundant, as both the `if` and the `else` blocks execute the same code; ② `moveToFolderCreationDate` and `folderCreationDate` are needlessly declared as properties, but suffice (and are more appropriate) as variables; ③ `set theFolder to theFolder as alias` will throw an error if `set theFolder to folders of alias...` contains more than one item in the returned result; ④ Could be worth explaining potential implications of a folder action that creates folders in the folder being monitored.

Comment: Thanks @CJK haven't added these edits yet as waiting for wch1zpink just to see if I'm missing something

Comment: There is no ever-ending loop here because when the script creates a folder, it then executes the script a second time to move that folder into itself; this will generate an error, and terminate the second-run of the script, so as far as the user is aware, nothing untoward appears to happen.  Strictly speaking, there's nothing especially wrong with this, but it's not necessarily the ideal way for execution to take place, and it's always good to understand what's happening behind the scenes, even if the outcome is seemingly benign.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example script that will move any new items added to any folder which has this script attached. You will, of course, have to replace `/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Weeklies` with whatever folder you store your weeklies in. It can be the Desktop, as the script will only affect new items.

```
-- move any new items into Weekly subfolder
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving newItems
    -- determine subfolder name
    set mondayMonday to the weekday of the (current date) as integer
    if mondayMonday is 1 then
        copy the (current date) - 6 * days to mondayDate
    else if mondayMonday is greater than 2 then
        copy the (current date) - (mondayMonday - 2) * days to mondayDate
    end if

    set subFolderName to fillZeroes(month of mondayDate as integer) & "-" & fillZeroes(day of mondayDate) & "-" & year of mondayDate
    set subFolderParent to POSIX file ("/Users/jerry/Documents/Weeklies/")
    set subFolderPath to (subFolderParent as string) & subFolderName

    tell application "Finder"
        --create folder if it doesn't already exist
        if not (exists subFolderPath) then
            make new folder at subFolderParent with properties {name:subFolderName}
        end if

        --copy folder alias subFolderPath to subFolder
        repeat with desktopItem in newItems
            if exists file named (name of desktopItem) in folder subFolderPath then
                set fileName to name of desktopItem as text
                set fileCounter to 1
                set fileNameWithCounter to fileName
                repeat while exists file named fileNameWithCounter in folder subFolderPath
                    --put the counter first, so as not to invalidate any file extension
                    set fileCounter to fileCounter + 1
                    set fileNameWithCounter to (fileCounter as text) & " " & fileName
                end repeat
                --DO NOT MOVE. Renaming will trigger a new folder action
                --moving will cancel the folder action, leaving remaining files on the desktop
                set name of desktopItem to fileNameWithCounter
            else
                move desktopItem to folder subFolderPath
            end if
        end repeat

    end tell
end adding folder items to

--turn any month or day number that is less than ten into two digits with a leading zero
on fillZeroes(theInteger)
    set integerString to theInteger as string
    if the length of integerString is 1 then set integerString to "0" & integerString
    return integerString
end fillZeroes
```

The tricky bit is when a file already exists in the destination folder with that name; by default, move will leave the item on the desktop if there is a conflicting name. And the only other option is to move with replacing, which will erase the previous file.

But renaming the file on the desktop will trigger a new folder action, leaving any subsequent files on the desktop. The trick appears to be to rename the file *without moving it*, allowing the newly-triggered folder action to handle it and letting this script move on to the remaining items.

Note that both Automator and AppleScript can be used for folder actions. This means that you don’t really need to have the folder generated weekly; it can be generated just-in-time instead, if that folder’s only purpose is to store items from your Folder Action.

You can have the Automator script that generates it also be the Folder Action; or you can have the AppleScript that moves items also generate it, as this script does.

If you want the script to fail if the folder hasn’t been generated, you would replace `make new folder at subFolderParent with properties {name:subFolderName}` with simply `return` to exit the script if there is no folder with the appropriate name.

Comment: `repeat with desktopItem in newItems` ought not to be necessary, as _Finder_'s `move` command can handle lists of file objects.  Therefore, you can just `move newItems to...`.

Comment: @CJK, You’re right. As long as the file names can be relied on to be unique, `move newItems to folder subFolderPath` will work. In testing that solution, however, I discovered that `move` will fail if a file with the same name already exists, and that it is tricky to rename and move, as that triggers a new instance of the folder action. The trick appears to be to rename and not move, so I’ve adjusted the script.